# Stripe Customer Portal with Multiple Subscriptions

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

I have set up the Stripe customer portal off the back of a Firebase project using the Firebase-Stripe extension. My customers can subscribe multiple times to the same type of subscription. One subscription per program. So they could buy 3 programs, all on the Starter Monthly option. The problem is each subscription listed in the customer portal looks the same, there is no unique ID. So if a customer decides to cancel one subscription, they have no way of knowing which one is which oi the customer portal. Can the Stripe customer portal be reconfigured to include the Subscription ID or the subscription metadata in the portal that customer see?

[image]

Comment: FYI, clicking the 'Show Cost Details' only shows pricing and tax, no unique identifiers

Answer (score 1):

Each time your customer subscribe to a same Subscription, generate a unique [description](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-description) for it. It will show in the Customer Portal.

Comment: In testing this, passing a description to the subscription via the checkout_session using the Firebase SDK does not change the description on the subscription object

Comment: It could be you were passing description to the Checkout Session object, not the Subscription object itself. Make sure you use subscription_data.description: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-description